# Modificar un array de objetos segun clave en javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, busqueda, nextjs, ts

Tengo un array de objetos del tipo:

```
sections = [
  {
    name: "primero",
    videos: []
  },
  {
    name: "segundo",
    videos: []
  }
]
```

Lo que pretengo hacer es un recorrido a otro array y si encuentro un objeto cuyo name coincida con alguno de sections, añado el objeto al array videos de la section en cuestión.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
const getSections = (masterclasses: IMasterclass[]) => {
  let sections: ISection[] = [];

  masterclasses.forEach((mc) => {
    const found = sections.find((e) => e.name === mc.section.name);
    console.log(mc.section, found, sections);
    if (found !== undefined) {
      found.videos.push(mc);
      sections = [...sections, found]; // Aquí quiero modificar la sección con el name que he encontrado, pero lo que hace es una copia de todo sections, y al final añade found
    } else {
      sections.push({
        name: mc.section.name,
        image: mc.section.image,
        videos: [mc],
      });
    }
  });

  console.log(sections);

  return sections;
};
```

Ejemplo de uso:
Estado inicial:

```
sections = []
```

Entra el primero mc al foreach:

```
mc = {
  /* datos varios sobre un vídeo*/
  id: 1,
  section: {
    name: 'Deportes',
  }
  /* datos varios sobre un vídeo */
}
```

Pasando el if, sections debería actualizarse a

```
sections = [
  {
    name: 'Deportes',
    videos: [{
      id: 1,
      /* Más datos sobre el vídeo */
    }]
  }
]
```

Si el segundo objeto del foreach también tiene sección 'Deportes', se añade el vídeo al listado de vídeos de la seccion 'Deportes', sino, se crea la nueva sección con el vídeo en cuestión.

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: Pregunta actualizada!

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que únicamente necesitas agregar los videos, sugiero algo así:

Primero, mediante el uso de reduce agrupamos todos los videos de las masterClasses, para crear un diccionario donde la clave sea el nombre de la sección.

Luego, mediante el uso de map, agregamos los videos a las secciones, obteniéndolas desde el diccionario.

```
const sections = [
  { name: 'deportes', videos: [] },
  { name: 'aventura', videos: [] },
];

const masterClasses = [
  { id: 1, section: { name: 'deportes', img: 'img_1', videos: [1, 2] } },
  { id: 3, section: { name: 'deportes', img: 'img_3', videos: [3, 4] } },
  { id: 5, section: { name: 'aventura', img: 'img_6', videos: [5, 6] } },
];

const masterClassVideosMap = masterClasses.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const accVideos = acc[cur.section.name] || [];

  return {
    ...acc,
    [cur.section.name]: [...accVideos, ...cur.section.videos],
  };
}, {});

const fullSections = sections.map((section) => {
  return {
    ...section,
    videos: masterClassVideosMap[section.name] || [],
  };
});

console.log(fullSections);
```

Resultado:

```
[
  { name: 'deportes', videos: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] },
  { name: 'aventura', videos: [ 5, 6 ] }
]
```